# Who kills my process? Crash generates SIGHUP?

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill

I have a python script running on my Ubuntu server. Occasionally I return to find a hangup SIGHUP message has been sent to the process, which definitely wasn't me.

The kernel logs in /var/log/kern.log are empty and there are no results with 'dmesg | grep -i kill' so this makes me conclude it wasn't the kernel. So... who or what could have sent the HANGUP message to the process if it wasn't me and it wasn't the kernel!? (Nobody else has access to the server.)
Is the only possible explanation a program crash which caused a SIGHUP to be generated and sent to the process?

Edit: I know the SIGHUP was sent as, coincidentally, I catch this for graceful termination of the program using:

```
kill -1 <pid>
```

with

```
def terminate(signum, frame):
    print('Time of termination: {}'.format(datetime.now()))
    sys.exit()
    quit()

signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, terminate)
```

Comment: Is it possible that my program crashes and this causes it to receive a terminate message?